# jQuery cross fading 2 images

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, fadeto

Hey all i am currently using this code below:

```
$('#tLight0').fadeTo(500,0.40, function() {
   var theToTurn = $(this).attr('data-toTurn');
   $(this).attr("src","site.com/Images/light_" + theToTurn + ".png");
}).fadeTo(300,1);
```

In order to cross fade my 2 images i have. However, the first image fades to about 40% transparent before the 2nd image begin to fade in.

What i am looking for is it to fade to (out) the first image and fade to (in) the second **at the same time**. Just like you see images being crossfaded.

I've tried all types of settings for fadeTo but it just doesnt seem to preform as how i just described it.

How can i modify my code above in order to get the results i am looking for?

Comment: You'll need two image elements, since a single image element can't contain more than one image at a time.

Comment: @KevinB when i tried adding 2 images next to each other one would still go away while the other was fading in.. and the second image would never be on top of the first.

Comment: *"and the second image would never be on top of the first."* it would if you positioned it that way with css. **!**

Answer (score 2):

Two images in the same container, absolutely positioned.

If you're going to 40%:

- fade out the first one
- fadeout callback: change the z-indexes to put the second one in front
- fadeout callback: fade in the second one

If you're going for a full fade (might be nicer)

- fade one the first one, fade in the second one (no callbacks, it happens at the same time)